# Is the function $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

> Is the function $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?
>
> $f(x, y)$ := $\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}$, if $(x, y)$ $\not= (0, 0)$
> and $f(0, 0) := 0$

My attempt:

$f(x, y)$ = $\frac{xy}{x+y}$ if $(x,y) > (0,0)$ and

$f(x, y)$ = $\frac{xy}{-(x+y)}$ if $(x,y) < (0,0)$

So using polar coordinates:

$f(x, y)$ = $\frac{xy}{x+y}$ = $\frac{rcos\theta sin\theta}{cos\theta + sin\theta}$, thus $|f(x,y)| <= r = {(x^2 + y^2)}^{0.5} $ and thus $f$ is continuous.

$f(x, y)$ = $\frac{xy}{-(x+y)}$ = $\frac{-rcos\theta sin\theta}{cos\theta + sin\theta}$, thus $|f(x,y)| <= - r = {-(x^2 + y^2)}^{0.5} $ and thus $f$ is not continuous.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $(x,y)<(0,0)$ and why should the expression of the function change ? Globally speaking, your answer is meaningless, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, then\begin{align}\left\lvert\frac{xy}{\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert}\right\rvert&=\frac{r^2\left\lvert\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\right\rvert}{r\bigl(\lvert\cos\theta\rvert+\lvert\sin\theta\rvert\bigr)}\\&\leqslant\frac r2,\end{align}since $\left\lvert\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\right\rvert\leqslant\frac12$ and $\cos\theta\rvert+\lvert\sin\theta\rvert\geqslant1$. So, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Using polar coordinates, the expression reduces to

$$r\frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta}{|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|},$$ where $r$ tends to $0$ and $\theta$ varies arbitrarily.

As the denominator cannot vanish, the angular factor is finite and the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for polar coordinates. Simply note that $|xy|\leq\max(|x|,|y|)^2$ and $|x|+|y|\geq\max(|x|,|y|)$, so $|f(x,y)|\leq\max(|x|,|y|)$, which tends to $0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y)\not =(0,0)$;

1) $x\not =0$;

$|\dfrac{xy}{|x|+|y|}| \le |y| \lt \sqrt{x^2+y^2};$

2) $y \not =0$;

$|\dfrac{xy}{|x|+|y|}| \le |x| \lt \sqrt{x^2+y^2};$

$\epsilon >0$ given.

Choose $\delta =\epsilon$.