# Continuity of a function at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

$$f(x, y) := \begin{cases}\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x|+|y|},&\ \text{ if }(x, y)\ne(0,0\\ \ \\ 0,&\ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}
$$

My attempt:

We know $|xy| \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$ and so $-\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \leq xy\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$.

Thus $$- \sin(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2))\leq \sin(xy) \leq  \sin(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)).$$

And hence, $$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)}{|x| + |y|}\leq\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x| + |y|}\leq-\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)}{|x| + |y|}.$$

Now using polar coordinates, it becomes

$$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}r^2)}{r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)} \leq\cdots$$

So by sandwich theorem,

$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}r^2)}{r(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)}$ tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $0$, so $f$ is continuous.

Is my attempt correct?

Any other suggestions please?

Comment: $a<b<c$ does not imply $\sin(a)<\sin(b)<\sin(c)$, since the sine function is not monotonically increasing. But you can say that $\sin(x)\leq x$ for $x \geq 0$ and $\sin(x) \geq -x$ for $x \leq 0$. In other words, $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$. Does that help?

Comment: Jojo.Have a look.at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536692/is-the-function-f-continuous-at-0-0/3536761#3536761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard for me to see what you are trying to achieve. The sine is not monotone everywhere, so you need to be careful if you apply it. You seem to reverse an inequality there, and I don't see why.

And, if you are going to use polar coordinates, you can use them directly, you gain nothing by the inequalities you try to use first.

Finally,  you don't really need polar coordinates: using the easy inequality $|\sin t|\leq|t|$, 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x|+|y|}\right|&=\frac{|\sin xy|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{|xy|}{|x|+|y|}
\leq\frac12\,\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}\\ \ \\
&=\frac12\,\left(\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}+\frac{y^2}{|x|+|y|} \right)\\ \ \\
&\leq \frac12\,\left( \frac{x^2}{|x|}+\frac{y^2}{|y|}\right)\\ \ \\
&=\frac12\,(|x|+|y|).
\end{align}
The estimate can actually be made a lot simpler (maybe switching the roles of $y$ and $x$ if $x=0$): 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x|+|y|}\right|&=\frac{|\sin xy|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{|xy|}{|x|+|y|}=\frac{|x|\,|y|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{|x|\,|y|}{|x|}=|y|.
\end{align}
Note that if $x=0$ or $y=0$, then no inequalities are needed as already $\sin xy=0$.

Comment: Martin.Your second last line: x or y (not both) could be zero, then your second last line is not defined.

Comment: @Peter: you are right, and I'll clarify. But if $x=0$ or $y=0$, then the original expression is $0$ and no inequalities are needed.

Comment: Martin.Noticed it, because did a similar problem, cf. my comment to Jojo.Greetings.